# how to construct a dictionary from join?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to build a dictionary for the below tuple list:

```
lst=[('ldb', 25), ('baseB', 4), ('code', 112), 
     ('cache-6', 55), ('Xauthority', 1), ('baseA', 4), 
     ('npmrc', 1), ('apmrc', 1),('gz', 190), 
     ('dbf', 1), ('lst', 2), ('markdown', 10), 
     ('sqlite-shm', 2), ('vsixmanifest', 4), ('ttf', 109), 
     ('pkl', 35), ('gitignore', 8), ('xml', 46)]
```

By using join like this:

```
op= {','.join( '\'%s\':%d'%i for i in lst)}
```

But the output `op` will be of type `set` as below!!

```
set(["'ldb':25,'baseB':4,'code':112,'cache-6':55, 'Xauthority':1,'baseA':4,'npmrc':1,'apmrc':1,
'gz':190,'dbf':1,'lst':2,'markdown':10,'sqlite-shm':2,'vsixmanifest':4,'ttf':109,'pkl':35,'gitignore':8,'xml':46"])
```

Some one correct me in getting `dictionary` instead of `set` 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just do `d = dict(lst)` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are creating a set, not a dictionary. Try this:

```
lst=[('ldb', 25), ('baseB', 4), ('code', 112), ('cache-6', 55), ('Xauthority', 1), ('baseA', 4), ('npmrc', 1), ('apmrc', 1), ('gz', 190), ('dbf', 1), ('lst', 2), ('markdown', 10), ('sqlite-shm', 2), ('vsixmanifest', 4), ('ttf', 109), ('pkl', 35), ('gitignore', 8), ('xml', 46)]

new_data = {a:b for a, b in lst}
```

Or, better yet:

```
new_data = dict(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
lst = [('ldb', 25), ('baseB', 4), ('code', 112), ('cache-6', 55), ('Xauthority', 1), ('baseA', 4), ('npmrc', 1),
   ('apmrc', 1), ('gz', 190), ('dbf', 1), ('lst', 2), ('markdown', 10), ('sqlite-shm', 2), ('vsixmanifest', 4),
   ('ttf', 109), ('pkl', 35), ('gitignore', 8), ('xml', 46)]

d = dict()
for i in lst:
    d[i[0]] = i[1]
print(d)
```